# How to show TV from a coaxial cable on an Apple Thunderbolt Display

Tags: thunderbolt-display, television

I'm leaning towards replacing my current monitor (an LG) with an Apple Thunderbolt Display. The display would mostly be used with my computer but I'd like to be able to watch TV with in occasionally. I don't see any way of getting input to the display other than via Thunderbolt in [the manual](http://manuals.info.apple.com/MANUALS/1000/MA1594/en_US/thunderbolt_display_getting_started.pdf). My TV signal arrives via a coaxial cable. How could I get the coax's output onto the display? I'm aware [elgato](http://www.elgato.com/) makes a product that could get the signal onto my computer, whose output I could then show on the big display. But is there a configuration that wouldn't require my computer to be in the loop?

Answer (score 3):

You might consider a TV tuner with HDMI output like this:

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815260027

Then an HDMI to Display Port or Mini Display Port (Thunderbolt is backwards compatible with Mini Display Port. Display Port would need an adapter to the Mini variety) like this:

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=962633

Shop around for devices such as these. No idea how well any setup would work, I'd love to hear back how well it works out.

Comment: [Apple has this to say](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC914LL/B/apple-thunderbolt-display-27-inch?fnode=53): "Customers with Macs that only support Mini DisplayPort output, such as the Mac Pro and MacBook, as well as previous generations of MacBook Pro, MacBook Air, Mac mini, and iMac can use the 27-inch LED Cinema Display." Does that mean this solution won't work after all?

Comment: Don't they use the Thunderbolt display in the Apple store to demo the Mac Pros? The current Mac Pro does not have Thunderbolt (the new one does). Then again, I am reading all over that Thunderbolt displays aren't recognized on Mini Displayport Macs. This is odd to me as Thunderbolt was touted to be Mini Displayport + data and backwards compatible.... It could be that the OS disables it (as Apple did with their external DVD drive on machines with internal drives)

Answer (score 0):

The answer appears to be no, there is no way to do this without a computer in the loop. See [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?p=18244728).